# WPF/AvalonDock: Switching StackPanel orientation depending on dock location

Tags: wpf, avalondock

I'm building an app in WPF, using AvalonDock, partly because I think it'll be useful but mostly to teach myself some WPF and to get used to that style of programming in general. I've constructed the main "toolbox" of the app as a dockable pane so that it can be moved, pulled out or auto-hidden so that the user can make the most of their screen space, and inside it, I'm using a StackPanel to arrange the various buttons.

Is there a (relatively simple) way to have the StackPanel orient vertically when the toolbox is docked on the left or right, but horizontally when docked at the top or bottom? I'm sure there must be some way to bind the orientation to something rather than setting it directly, but I can't seem to find anything useful to bind it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like that:

Your StackPanel should be the following:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="{Binding DockableStyle, 
                         RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Avalon:DockableContent}},
                         Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}">
  <!-- StackPanel content here -->
</StackPanel>
```

Your `Myconverter` having the following as a `Convert` method:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
  DockableStyle style = value as DockableStyle
  if (style == DockableStyle.TopBorder || style == DockableStyle.BottomBorder)
  {
     return Orientation.Horizontal;
  }
  else
  {
     return Orientation.Vertical;
  }
}
```

I think this should do all the magic for you

Comment: That looks like it's along the right lines... Having a little trouble implementing it though; it compiles, but at runtime it informs me that 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.', which I think is because of the `StaticResource` binding on the converter... Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You probably forgot to declare your converter in your XAML resources! When you add a converter you always have to do the following:
In your `UserControl` (or `Window`, or `Page`, or... The first tag) opening tag, add:
`xmlns:myTag="clr-namespace:MyConverterNamespace"`
(of course, the `myTag` name is completely up to you. Visual Studio should propose to autocomplete the namespace anyway)
Then, in your `Resources` (put it wherever it's needed), add :
<myTag:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter" />
=> This will declare your converter in your `StaticResource`s =)

Comment: Ah, that explains a few things. I knew you had to do that, but apparently I was doing it wrong.
Still throwing an error though... this is a weird one. If I take the StackPanel opening tag you suggested out and replace it with a basic `<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">` then it works, but with your version in, it throws an exception on the line BEFORE your bit, which is `<ad:DockableContent x:Name="Toolbar" Title="Tools" DockableStyle="AutoHide" IsCloseable="False">`. I can't seem to figure out why... Sorry to keep asking questions; I'm new to this.